# How to create a bond between two nodes using bondcpp

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am running ros jade on ubuntu 14.04. I need to monitor node crashes.I think bondcpp can help me do that.However, I can't find the example code given to work

node A

```
#include <bondcpp/bond.h>

std::string id = generateUniqueId();
// Sends id to B using a service or action
bond::Bond bond("example_bond_topic", id);
bond.start();
if (!bond.waitUntilFormed(ros::Duration(1.0)))
{
    ROS_ERROR("ERROR!");
    return false;
}
// ... do things with B ...
bond.waitUntilBroken(ros::Duration(-1.0));


printf("B has broken the bond\n");
```

and another node -node B

```
#include <bondcpp/bond.h>

// Receives id from A using a service or action
bond::Bond bond("example_bond_topic", id);
bond.start();
// ... do things ...
bond.breakBond();
```

Node A never goes beyond that "ERROR!".
Any advice will be appreciated
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258465/how-to-create-a-bond-between-two-nodes-using-bondcpp/) by [eesttaar](https://answers.ros.org/users/22855/eesttaar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2017-04-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mohsen1989m](https://answers.ros.org/users/22803/mohsen1989m/) on 2017-04-04**:
if u wanna track where your node crashes why don't u just use gdb?

**Comment by [eesttaar](https://answers.ros.org/users/22855/eesttaar/) on 2017-04-05**:
More than where I am interested in when so that I can take subsequent actions like respawning or informing other nodes in the system that a particular node has crashed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're getting that "ERROR!" string the bond is not getting initialized within 1 second so is erroring.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0